# Remove one of the two instances of MySQL?

Tags: macos, mac, mysql, imac, mamp

### Objective

I want to get rid of one of the two instances of MySQL on my iMac.

### History

A while back I installed one just to play around with it - but then I ended up installing a MAMP stack so that I could do PHP development. When I did that it installed a version of MySQL as well - so now I have two of them running.

### Research

So, I ran a `netstat -n | grep mysql` and got back the following results:

[image: Running MySQL Instances]

However, I don't know how to get the one that's ***not*** in the **MAMP** directory off of my machine. Please direct me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find / -name mysql` to find all occurrences of *mysql* to find where mysql instances are installed.

Or you can have a look at `/usr/local`. That's where normally external mysql-instances are installed to. If you find a mysql-folder in there you can safely remove that **if you definitely do not need that one**. Don't forget to remove the symbolic link also.

You should then also have a look at `/Library/StartupItems` which could contain a folder named MSYQL-something (right now not sure about the exact name) which you can also delete. It's the stuff that start your MySQL-Database during the boot-process.

And then there's the MySQL-PreferencePane you can remove. It should be located at `/Library/PreferencePanes`. Simply move it to the Trash and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the pid from the 2nd column from

```
sudo lsof | grep mysql.sock
```

would result

```
mysqld     303         _mysql   12u     unix 0x54d946e8e8d9b067       0t0                     /tmp/mysql.sock
```

with the pid, you can have list the instances with `ps axu | grep mysql` , where the 2nd column is the pid.

Comment: OK, from there how do I *remove* that instance of MySQL completely from my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was like this.

Go to /Library/PreferencePanes and open the MySQL.prefPane file,

and you will see mysql control window.

there are stop mysql button and check box for Automatically Start Mysql server on start up.

then you are done.

netstat -n | grep mysql

then you can see it is removed.

Comment: How, exactly, does this address the issue of there being ***two** copies* of MySQL (and the OP wanting to remove *only one* of them)?

Comment: this will stop mysqld     303         _mysql   12u     unix 0x54d946e8e8d9b067       0t0                     /tmp/mysql.sock. and you can use mamp mysql without any issue